# using jQuery post to ASP.Net webapi

Tags: jquery, post, asp.net-web-api

Having some trouble:

I do this simple test and the alert pops up the text "test return simple":

jQuery post:

```
$.post("http://www.localhost/webapi/api/corkboard/test/", jsonData)
            .done(function(data){
                alert(data);
        });
```

Asp.Net WebAPI:

```
[HttpPost]
public string test()
{        
    return "test return simple";
}
```

But when I change the WebAPI by adding a parameter:

```
public string test(string JSONData)
    {
        var jData = Json.Decode(JSONData);
        return "test return: " + jData.Filter;            
    }
```

I get the following error message:

"No HTTP resource was found that matches the request URI 'http://www.localhost/webapi/api/corkboard/test/'

Stuck and would appreciate any thoughts ... thanks !

Comment: What web server are you using as your backend? The specific technology should define how to handle post-methods and the data coming in as a POST request. It might not be as straighforward as just adding a parameter in your POST method handler.

Comment: I am using .net WebAPI ... I'm trying to follow some existing code that I found that uses the same architecture: jquery post and .net webapi ... but I'm snagged on this part ...

Comment: I am not an expert on .net webapi but found a link which talks about how to configure your GET, POST and other HTTP handlers: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/549152/Introduction-to-ASP-NET-Web-API

Comment: Thanks Stony. I'll look at it later when I get a chance ... ;-)

Comment: I tried changing the first line in the jQuery request by adding the jsonData as a URL parameter and it worked. But I don't want to pass data in the URL. I guess I need to understand clearly how data is passed from client to server. Here's my change: $.post("http://localhost/webapi/api/corkboard/test?JSONData=" + jsonData)

Comment: No matter how you posted, if you don't want to create model for some reason, access all posted data from `HttpContext.Current.Request.Form.AllKeys` or specific key `HttpContext.Current.Request.Form["name"]` remember I'm posting data like this `$.post('url', { name: 'some', id: '123' })`

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Change your WebApi method to:

```
public string test([FromBody]string JSONData)
    {
        var jData = Json.Decode(JSONData);
        return "test return: " + jData.Filter;            
    }
```

and your JQuery to:

```
$.post('http://www.localhost/webapi/api/corkboard/test/', { '': jsonData })
        .done(function(data){
            alert(data);
    });
```

Comment: Bravo, this works. Tks. But man, the syntax is really quirky and I was not familiar with it ... for further details, see the Encosia.com article in the post by J. Marley. - cheers !

Answer (score 6):

Try the following code..

```
$.post("http://www.localhost/webapi/api/corkboard/test/", { value: jsonData })
            .done(function(data){
                alert(data);
        });
```

Or, you can check the following link..

http://encosia.com/using-jquery-to-post-frombody-parameters-to-web-api/

Comment: The link has valuable and well explained details. Thanks.

Comment: Chrome says that link also contains malware just so ya know.