# ASP.NET Core: POSTing complex type from jQuery always results in 'null' model

Tags: asp.net-core

I'm trying to POST to my ASP.NET Core (RC1) API from jQuery. It works fine when I POST via HttpClient, so I think it's only a stupid thing I'm missing.

I can reproduce my problem on a vanilla default ASP.NET 5 project and this code.

**Server**

```
namespace WebApplication1.Controllers
{
    [Route("api/[controller]")]
    public class ValuesController : Controller
    {
        [HttpPost]
        public IActionResult Post([FromBody]Model input)
        {
            // input is always null

            return Json(input.Value);
        }


        public class Model
        {
            public string Value { get; set; }
        }
    }
}
```

**Client**

```
$.ajax({
    url: "http://localhost:5000/api/values",
    method: "POST",
    contentType: "application/json",
    dataType: "json",
    data: JSON.stringify({
        Value: "some_value"
    })
}).done(function(data) {
    console.log("Done.", data);                         
});
```

I played around by removing `[FromBody]`, that returns a model, but the properties were never populated. I also tried the many solutions and workarounds for similar problems on SO, but I think they don't apply to .NET Core or only solve problems usinf `[FromBody]` and simple types. For example [Web Api Parameter always null](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14624306/web-api-parameter-always-null) or [using jQuery post to ASP.Net webapi](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19627045/using-jquery-post-to-asp-net-webapi) or http://encosia.com/using-jquery-to-post-frombody-parameters-to-web-api/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I took another few hours until I finally figured it out. As I feared/hoped, it was only one stupid thing:

It took Fiddler to discover that I had minor problems with my CORS configuration. Realizing that I disabled CORS completely in Chrome and it suddenly started to work. The server-side code worked as-is, this is the minimal working client-side code:

```
$.ajax({
    url: "http://localhost:5000/api/values",
    method: "POST",
    contentType: "application/json",
    data: JSON.stringify({
        value: "some_value"
    })
}).done(function(data) {
    console.log("Done.", data);                         
});
```

Please note that `contentType` is required, without it the modelbinding won't work.

Of course, I had tried this client-side code before, but CORS funked it up: There is an OPTION request for CORS to determine if the request is valid. The browser F12 tools don't make this as obvious as it should be. Interestingly I received the OPTION request in the debugger (and that's why I thought it worked), but I finally discovered via Fiddler that the `contentType` header was not correctly transmitted in these requests - and that's why the model was not bound correctly.