# How to make POST with parameters>

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-webapi

I try to make simple POST request to WebApi:

```
http://localhost::60310/locations/15
```

Full request are:

```
https://imgur.com/a/FggUJ
```

My controller:

```
[Produces("application/json")]
[Route("/Locations")]
public class LocationsController : Controller
{
 [HttpPost("{id}")]
    public async Task<IActionResult> PutLocation()
     {
       var distance= Request.Form.FirstOrDefault(p => p.Key == "distance").Value;
        var city = Request.Form.FirstOrDefault(p => p.Key == "city").Value;
        var place= Request.Form.FirstOrDefault(p => p.Key == "place").Value;
        var county= Request.Form.FirstOrDefault(p => p.Key == "country").Value;
        var id = Request.Form.FirstOrDefault(p => p.Key == "id").Value;

      //some code
     }
 }
```

So, i have data class:

```
  public class Location
{
    [JsonProperty("distance")]
    public int Distance { get; set; }
    [JsonProperty("city")]
    public string City { get; set; }
    [JsonProperty("place")]
    public string Place { get; set; }
    [JsonProperty("id")]
    public int Id { get; set; }
    [JsonProperty("country")]
    public string Country { get; set; }
}
```

When i try to test this request (by Postman) i have 200 code.
But, when i make breakpoint into this method- it does not work.
So, as i assume, this method do not call by framework.

Can you help me: why this method do not call?And how to fix that?

Comment: Your url contains two colons (::), should be one.

Comment: Share your jquery or post code

Comment: @QaiserMehmood, i have not this code. I have only Web Api.

Comment: This may help you. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19627045/using-jquery-post-to-asp-net-webapi